# How to specify date-format using csv2rec-method

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, format

I am reading a csv-File using matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec. The first column consist of dates in the format

```
"DD.MM.YYYY  hh:mm"
```

The dates are correctly transformed into datetime-objects as long as the day is > 12. As soon as the day is < 12, it is interpreted as a month.

For example: `"13.09.2012  15:45"` is correctly interpreted as September, 13th 2012 while `"12.09.2012  15:45"` is interpreted as December, 9th 2012, although it should be interpreted as September, 12th 2012.

Is there a way in which I can specify the datetime-format the csv2rec-method should use when reading dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can specify converting function using converterd parameter](http://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html#matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec).

Following code assume that datatime field is the first column.

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.mlab

print matplotlib.mlab.csv2rec('data.csv', converterd={
    0: lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'),
})
```